# count a specific row on a nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to count the number of records on a particular field with the query below.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN seen='n' and reciever_id=1 THEN 'varb' ELSE  'novarb' END) AS count ,c.id, c.vmsg, c.sender_id, p.fname, p.lname, p.profile_pix, p.profile_id
FROM chats c LEFT JOIN profile p  ON c.sender_id = p.profile_id
WHERE c.reciever_id = 1 AND c.id in (SELECT MAX(c.id) as id FROM  chats c
GROUP BY c.sender_id )
```

But the answer i get only returns it just one record whiles there other hundreds to be displayed

Comment: Can u create a fiddle for this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `varb` and `novarb` the dictinct count is max 2  if you have 1 mean that you have one condition only

could be you need that count the number of `varb` entries

```
SELECT COUNT(
            CASE WHEN seen ='n' and reciever_id=1 
                    THEN 'varb' 
                    ELSE  NULL
            END) AS count ,c.id, c.vmsg, c.sender_id, p.fname, p.lname, p.profile_pix, p.profile_id
FROM chats c 
LEFT JOIN profile p  ON c.sender_id = p.profile_id
WHERE c.reciever_id = 1 AND c.id in (
      SELECT MAX(c.id) as id FROM  chats c
      GROUP BY c.sender_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `SUM()` for this purpose.  If I understand correctly, you want the number of rows that meet the condition and don't meet the condition:

```
SELECT SUM( seen = 'n' and reciever_id = 1 ) as varb,
       SUM( not (seen = 'n' and reciever_id = 1) ) as novarb,
       c.id, c.vmsg, c.sender_id, p.fname, p.lname, p.profile_pix, p.profile_id
FROM chats c JOIN  -- I doubt a left join is necessary
     profile p
     ON c.sender_id = p.profile_id
WHERE c.reciever_id = 1 AND
      c.id in (SELECT MAX(c2.id) FROM  chats c2 GROUP BY c2.sender_id)
```